# Creating a Generic DbSet.Find() query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a database with 3 tables for classes that all implement my IMeetingEntityEntityBaseClass.cs

```
public class BookingAppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public BookingAppDbContext(DbContextOptions<BookingAppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        
        public DbSet<MeetingSpace> MeetingSpaces { get; set; } 
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; } 
        public DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; } 
    }
```

I started off with only the MeetingSpaces table and was trying to make my database operation methods generic so they could be reused for the other two tables. However they (and my ASP.NET pages) rely on the Id to identify the meeting space. My problem is that I cant figure out how to make the GetById class generic. For the MeetingSpace table query it is as follows:

```
public MeetingSpace GetById(int id)
        {
            return db.MeetingSpaces.Find(id);
        }
```

I attempted to use the Find overload with the type specified but the typeof(T) returns 'object', throwing an error that type 'object' cannot be converted to 'T'.

```
public T GetById<T>(int id) where T : IMeetingEntityBaseClass
        {
            return db.Find(typeof(T), id);
        }
```

Comment: `db.Set<T>().Find(id)`

Comment: Also, how are you calling this method? If `typeof(T)` is giving you `object` then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @DavidG replacing my query with yours gives the following error:  CS0119 'DbContext.Set<TEntity>()' is a method, which is not valid in the given context BookingApp.Data C:\Users\C76061A\source\repos\grad-nyle-booking-app\BookingApp\BookingApp.Data\SqlMeetingSpaceData.cs

Comment: Did you type it exactly as I wrote it? Did you miss the `()`?

Comment: @DavidG. Sorry, yes I had made a mistake with the brackets. I have pasted your line and am getting the error:  CS0452 The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbContext.Set<TEntity>()

Comment: Ah yes, you also need to add a type constraint. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`DbContext.Set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-5.0) method. Also, you need to add a type constraint since the `Set` method relies in it (as do all EF entities.) For example:

```
public T GetById<T>(int id) 
    where T : class, IMeetingEntityBaseClass
{
    return db.Set<T>().Find(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks David for your help, this solution works. One small note was that the class constrain has to be called first.

Comment: Ah yes good spot. I wrote all that from memory and forgot about the ordering. Fixed it now!

Comment: Impressive memory, I had visual studio to remind me!